# stackFromEnd for RecyclerView but in Compose LazyColumn?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In `RecyclerView` we can use `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)` to keep the position of list bottom.

With `LazyColumn`, the only way to do this is use `reverseLayout = true`, but it breaks display order.

It's somthing looks like `adjustPan` window, but I want it works in `adjustResize` window.

[lazycolumn vs recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdMnV.gif)

Comment: Well, seems not possible by now. `rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy` is always based on firstVisibleItemScrollOffset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `reverseLayout` in Lazycolumn.

```
@Composable
fun ItemList(items: List<String>) {

    LazyColumn(
        reverseLayout = true
    ) {
        items(items) { item ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .height(100.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
              
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = item
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's paging list. It's hard to reverse data order.

Answer (score 0):

Make Scaffold the parent layout and add your bottom EditText as the bottomBar component of the parent.

```
Scaffold(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), 
         bottomBar = { MySearchBarBox() }) { paddingValues ->
            MyList(...)
        }
```

and a LazyColumn example:

```
@Composable
internal fun MyList(...) {
    
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()   
    val items = viewModel.getItems.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    val state = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
        state = state,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        reverseLayout = true
    ) {
         // always scroll to show the latest item
        scope.launch {
            state.scrollToItem(0)
        }

        items(
            count = items.itemCount,
            key = items.itemKey { it.getItemId() },
            contentType = items.itemContentType { it.getDataType() }
        ) { index ->
            items[index]?.let {
                ... // your row ui here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but use scrollToItem here was not correct due to recompose. Also `reverseLayout = true` reversed the order.